# How to use AES256 in PHP - encryption / decryption

Tags: php, security, encryption, aes

I already use some sha1/MD5 encryption techniques but i need to create a PHP class to encrypt/decrypt data using AES-256 with strong security. How can i do that ? I saw a lot of code over the net (thks to google) but don't find clear way to implement it

Comment: I finally found something in various places and i create a small class which is a yii (php framework) plugin. You could look at it and use it on yii project or any php project. Feel free to comment this.  [https://github.com/lucbonnin/aes256_yii_extension](https://github.com/lucbonnin/aes256_yii_extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found something in various places and i create a small class which is a yii (php framework) plugin. You could look at it and use it on yii project or any php project. Feel free to comment this.

https://github.com/lucbonnin/aes256_yii_extension

Comment: On a first glance the implementation looks pretty decent. I would probably upvote it, but link-only answers are frowned upon on Stackoverflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/196445

Comment: No, this code uses MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 instead of AES-256 and doesn't compare MACs in a time-invariant manner. I don't recommend it, as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Just use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 with 256 bit key

Check this out: https://gist.github.com/RiANOl/1077723

Comment: You can just add $IV = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);

Comment: Erm, if you specify `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` then you will get AES128. mcrypt is awful enough to not care about the actual length of the supplied key.

Comment: @Timur: Two things: 1. Never use MCRYPT_RAND, it's insecure. MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM is your friend. 2. Patch it and tell me if it works. (Unless you pass the IV with ciphertext, it will generate a completely different IV for decryption and break.) Perseids: Nope! MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 is AES. If you pass a 256-bit key, you get AES-256. Some people treat MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 as if it were AES-256, but AES is strictly a 128-bit flavor of Rijndael. Rijndael-256 is a different block cipher. It's not the same thing.